# Tips for more elegant code for creating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm creating a dictionary with keys and values from lists:

```
keys = ['Ptot', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']
val = ['max', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first']
```

I can manually create the dictionary by the following:

```
dictionary = {'Ptot': 'max', 'P1': 'first', 'P2': 'first', 'P3': 'first', 'Q1': 'first', 'Q2': 'first', 'Q3': 'first'}
```

How can I more elegantly create the dict from the lists by a for-loop? My problem is that the size of the lists are much bigger than this example.

Comment: are they always the same size ?

Comment: `d = {}
for k,v in zip(keys,val): d[k] = v`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a dictionary comprehension, where you choose your key and value from the `keys` and `val` list as you are iterating over them, and just to be safe if the `keys` and `val` are of unequal lengths, you can zip all of them together via [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), which will create an iterator of the longest subsequence, making sure if say `keys` is longer than `val`, we have None keys for them, maybe to reassign them in future (Thanks @quamrana)

```
from itertools import zip_longest
keys = ['Ptot', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']
val = ['max', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first']

print({k:v for k,v in zip_longest(keys, val)})
```

Output is

```
{'Ptot': 'max', 'P1': 'first', 'P2': 'first', 'P3': 'first', 'Q1': 'first', 'Q2': 'first', 'Q3': 'first'}
```

An example of bigger length of `keys` then `val`

```
from itertools import zip_longest
keys = ['Ptot', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'QX', 'QY']
val = ['max', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first']

print({k:v for k,v in zip_longest(keys, val)})
```

Output will be

```
{'Ptot': 'max', 'P1': 'first', 'P2': 'first', 
'P3': 'first', 'Q1': 'first', 'Q2': 'first', 'Q3': 'first', 
'QX': None, 'QY': None}
```

so we see that the keys are not lost here, but are used and the values set to None, but using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will cause us to lose those keys!

But in case we want to only choose elements from the smaller list, we can do as follows (thanks @MitchelPaulin)

```
from itertools import zip_longest
keys = ['Ptot', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'QX', 'QY']
val = ['max', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first', 'first']

#Pick the smaller of the 2 lengths and iterate only on those indexes
length = min(len(keys), len(val))
print({keys[idx]:val[idx] for idx in range(length)})
```

Comment: Might want to use `min(len(keys), len(val))` just to be safe

Comment: This will only work if both `keys` and `val` contain equal number of elements

Comment: You could `zip` the `keys` and `vals` together.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> d = dict(zip(keys, val))
>>> d
{'Ptot': 'max', 'P1': 'first', 'P2': 'first', 'P3': 'first', 'Q1': 'first', 'Q2': 'first', 'Q3': 'first'}
```

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>
> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

Then we pass the return value to `dict` to create a dictionary. This is probably more efficient than a simple loop since built-ins run at C speed within Python and the implementors probably had more time to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses `zip` with simple appending of the second list to match the sizes.

```
l1=['Ptot', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4' ]
l2=['max', 'first' ]

# make sure we have the same length
for i in range (len(l1)-len(l2)): l2.append(None)

d={}
d={k:v for k,v in zip(l1,l2)}
print(d)
```

Note that I used `append(None)` like [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) uses `fillvalue=None`.

---

```
{'Ptot': 'max', 'P1': 'first', 'P2': None, 'P3': None, 'Q1': None, 'Q2': None, 'Q3': None, 'Q4': None}
```